# Issue with downloading a specific image file via HTTP call, resulting in a invalid file

Tags: c#, image, http, download, jpeg

I'm currently trying to download an image file from a specific URL using an HTTP call. However, the resulting file is always an file with invalid format, even though the image can be downloaded successfully through a web browser. This issue doesn't occur with other files from same server and of same type, and I'm not able to pinpoint the cause for this.

I tried add all the headers that are added when the browser makes the same call through copying the headers from network tab of chrome. It still produced the same invalid file.

I have confirmed the following things so far :

1. The status code is 200, so there is no redirect involved.
2. The downloaded file has same byte size as specified in content length header so no partial download as well.
3. Able to download other files with same filetype from same server so no issues with server or the actual filetype.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
{

    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(fileUrl),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        };
        AddHeaders(request);
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("br"));

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(response.AsFormattedString());
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(response.GetContentHeaders());
            Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
            string fileSavePath = Path.Combine(outputFolderPath,Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".jpg");

            using (Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileSavePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                Task task = stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                task.Wait();
            }

            return fileSavePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to add c# tag to this question. Also, you could add more logging to capture more details about response you get back and add that to your question.